# Why does present conditional of devoir translate English 'should'?

Tags: étymologie

I am [ESL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_as_a_second_or_foreign_language). I do not know Latin. User None [commented](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/49293/why-does-present-conditional-of-devoir-translate-english-should#comment99532_49293)

> Anyway you should bear in mind that *Should* is the past tense of *shall*, and shall was used in Old English to express necessity/obligation (OED). *Should* is the modal verb that is used to express (among other things) a moral obligation and the conditional. *Devoir* comes from Latin *debere* an auxiliary verb that indicates necessity, obligation. *Devoir* has kept that meaning all along.

1. I still don't grok the semantic relationship between English 'should', with Latin  *debere*  ⟶ French *devoir*. Why did French choose Latin *debere* and French *devoir* to translate 'should'?
2. Why does French use the present conditional of *devoir*?

> #### 11.3.2 ‘should’
>
> ’should’ has four main meanings:
>
> **(a)** ‘should’ may indicate a moral obligation. This is usually rendered by the use of *devoir*:
>
> > Tu **devrais** téléphoner chez toi plus souvent.
> > *You **should** phone home more often*.
> > (*devoir* in the conditional form to indicate the moral duty)

Roger Hawkins and Richard Towell, *French Grammar and Usage* (2015 4 edn), p 279.

[DEVOIR : Définition de DEVOIR](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/devoir)

> **Prononc. et Orth. :** [d(ə)vwa:ʀ], *(je) dois* [dwa]. Ds *Ac.* 1694-1932. Homon. *devant* (prép.), *dois, doit, doigt.* **Étymol. et Hist. A.** *Devoir* + inf., rôle d'auxil. **1.** 842 marque l'obligation, la nécessité (*Serments de Strasbourg* ds Henry, p. 1 : **dift** [3epers. du sing. de l'ind. prés.]); fin xes. *deveir* (*Passion de Clermont, ibid.,* p. 4, 33); **2.** *ca* 1050 marque le futur (*Alexis,* éd. Chr. Storey, 279); **3.** *ca* 1100 *devoir* marque la probabilité (*Roland,* éd. J. Bédier, 389 : Li soens orgoilz le **devreit** bien confondre); **4.** *id.* marque un souhait (*ibid.,* 1149 : Li emperere nos **devreit** bien venger); **5.** *id.* marque l'intention (*ibid.,* 333). **B.** *Devoir* + compl. d'obj. dir. *ca* 1155 « être tenu, légalement ou moralement, de donner ou de restituer quelque chose à quelqu'un » (Wace, *St Nicolas,* éd. E. Ronsjö, 808); av. 1188 « être redevable de quelque chose » (*Partonopeus de Blois,* éd. J. Gildea, 6891). **C.** *Devoir* (*à qqn* ou *à qqc.*) *de* + inf. 1784 « être redevable de » (Beaumarchais, *Mère coupable,* I, 8 ds Littré). Du lat. class. *debĕre,* de mêmes sens.

Comment: You can look up etymology online. I doubt you mean that word though. French has a conjugated verb for "should" as in have a duty to. **English does not**. English only has modal: should + a verb. So, tu devrais faire x becomes You should do x.  In any case, this forum doesn't really deal with French-into-English issues.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking. Anyway you should bear in mind that *Should* is the past tense of *shall*, and [*shall*](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=shall)  was used in Old English to express necessity/obligation (OED). *Should* is the modal verb that is used to express (among other things) a [moral obligation and the conditional](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/should). (to be continued)

Comment: (continued) *Devoir* comes from Latin [*debere*](https://www.dicolatin.com/Latin/Lemme/0/DEBERE/index.html) an auxiliary verb that indicates necessity, obligation. *Devoir* has kept that meaning all along. Different etymologies and histories but lots of common points.  In French the conditional is formed by modifying the endings of verbs.

Comment: *Why did French choose Latin debere and French devoir to translate 'should'?* Or did English translators choose 'should' to translate 'devoir', don't you think ?

Comment: French never "chose" anything, neither did English. Languages have histories, they move along, and they started  doing so long before they even "met" and people started translating into other languages. You should maybe consider trying to  relate languages in the form ideas instead of words. Word for word correspondance doesn' t work.

Comment: If you ask about the etymology of a French word most of the time the answer will refer to Latin since most of the French vocabulary and a good deal of its grammar come from Latin. You don't need to know Latin to understand the etymology of a word. Very very few speakers of French know Latin.

Comment: There is no semantic relationship at all between devoir [verb] and should [verb]. Why should there be??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's refer to the etymolgy of [**should**](https://www.etymonline.com/word/should) to see the connection :

> **Should**
> c. 1200, from Old English sceolde, past tense of sceal (see shall). Preserves the original notion of "obligation" that has all but dropped from shall.

an for **shall** (emphasis mine) :

> Old English sceal, Northumbrian scule "I **owe**/he owes, will have to, ought to, must" (infinitive sculan, past tense sceolde), a common Germanic preterite-present verb (along with can, may, will), from Proto-Germanic *skal- (source also of Old Saxon sculan, Old Frisian skil, Old Norse and Swedish skola, Middle Dutch sullen, Old High German solan, German sollen, Gothic skulan "to **owe**, be under obligation;" related via past tense form to Old English scyld "guilt," German Schuld "guilt, **debt**;" also Old Norse Skuld, name of one of the Norns), from PIE root *skel- (2) "to be under an obligation."

I think we can see a connection to the notion of *debt / to owe something* with the French equivalent *devoir*.

I'm no translation expert, but here what I understand:

> *he shall do something*

may be rendered with the indicative mood of devoir or the future tense :

> - *il doit faire quelque chose* (obligation)
> - *il fera quelquechose* (futur),

Now as a modified/weakened version of *shall*, *should* may be rendered with conditionnal mood of *devoir*:

> *he should do something*

> *il devrait faire quelque chose* (conseil, suggestion)

Comment: Il doit faire quelque chose. is not He shall do something. It's: He should do something.

Comment: Comme vous le savez, *shall* n'a pas d'équivalent exact en Français. "Il doit faire quelque chose" est bien une des traductions possibles pour *he shall do something* (cf. [DeepL](https://www.deepl.com/fr/translator#en/fr/He%20shall%20do%20something) par ex.).  *Should* est plus facile et c'est généralement traduit "devrait". (cf Deepl et google trad par ex.)

Comment: J'aurais du m'en douter. Deepl. Tous ces sites sont bourrés d'erreurs. He shall do something=il fera x. He shall do it. n'est pas Il doit faire quelque chose. Quelle idée....

Comment: Comme dit plus haut ce n'est pas la seule traduction possible suivant le contexte, je vous laisse faire vos recherches.

Comment: Je n'ai pas besoin de faire des recherches. Je parle suffisamment bien les deux langues pour savoir ce que je dis. He shall do something. ne veut pas dire en aucun cas Il doit faire quelque chose.

Comment: Pas besoin d'aller chercher très loin pour voir de multiple façon de traduire shall (devoir, futur, pouvoir etc.): https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=auto&query=he+shall ou encore https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=auto&query=he+shall+not. Et ce n'est pas un complot de linguee (ce sont des sources diverses).

Comment: He shall do something. ne sera jamais: Il doit faire quelque chose. D'autre part, on ne traduit pas "shall". on traduit: shall suivi d'un verbe ou bien comme une réponse court: Yes, he shall. Ce qui se traduit selon le verbe dans la phrase précédente. Aussi, l'utilisation pour faire un service à quelqu'un: Shall I open the window? Devrais-je ouvrir la fenêtre? Ou: Voulez-vous que j'ouvre la fenêtre?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

*Devoir* is used in the present tense to (among other things) indicate **strong** obligation. "*Tu dois*" = "*You must, you have too*".

Conditional is used to "**soften**" that obligation. "*Tu devrais*" = "*You should, you ought to*". That's about it, you don't need to go as far as the Latin etymology.

---

It's not just *devoir*. For instance *Falloir* works the same way. "*Il faut ...*" = "*I/you/one must ...*, "*Il faudrait ...*" = "I/you/one should ...*".

There's also *vouloir*, where *je voudrais* is used as a softened and more polite *je veux* (*I want*).

I would even say this can apply to any verb when reporting events, to "soften" the affirmation, to mitigate how certain we are of the facts. For example, when reporting crimes or other news, a sentence using "*allegedly*" or "*reportedly*" in English would use conditional in French.

> Le coupable **se serait enfui** à pied

> The culprit **allegedly fled** the scene on foot